# Why am i getting this error "react Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component" in the following code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

import { useResultContext } from '../contexts/ResultContextProvider';

export const Results = () => {
  const {getResults, results, isLoading, searchTerm} = useResultContext();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [num, setNum] = useState(10);

  const changeNum=()=>{
    setNum(num+10);
    console.log(num)
    Results();
}

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(searchTerm){
    if (location.pathname ==='/videos') {
      getResults(`/search/q=${searchTerm} videos&num=${num}`)
    }else{
      getResults(`${location.pathname}/q=${searchTerm}&num=${num}`)
    }
  }
  },[location.pathname, searchTerm, num, getResults]);


  switch (location.pathname) {
    case '/search':
      return (<><div className='flex flex-wrap justify-between space-y-6 sm:px-56 overflow-hidden pb-4 '>
        {
          results?.results?.map(({link, title, description}, index)=>(
            <div key={index} className='md:w-3/5 w-full'>
              <a href={link} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                <p className='text-sm text-green-700'>
                  {link.length>50? link.substring(0,50): link}
                </p>
                <p className='text-lg hover:underline dark:text-blue-300 text-blue-700'>
                  {title}
                </p>
              </a>
              {description.length>15?
                <p>
                  {description}
                </p>:''}
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
      <div onClick={changeNum} className='absolute bg-gray-200 border border-gray-400 py-3 px-10 rounded-full -mt-5 left-96 cursor-pointer active:bg-gray-300 dark:bg-gray-700 '>
        More Results
      </div>
      </>);
    default: return 'ERROR';
  }
  
};
```

I've started learning react and it's been two days i have been unable to get around this.

I'm trying to make google search engine clone and in this project i'm getting results using google search api and displaying 10 results at first and want then to increase by 10 every time when i click on 'More Results' button which calls 'changeNum' function which uses 'setNum' to add 10 value to 'num' every time function is called by clicking on button.

EDIT: i shortened the code by removing some cases

Comment: How do you use `Results`?

Comment: If you're using react-router-dom why don't you use routes instead using a `switch` in your component?

Comment: @CertainPerformance to print results on page

Comment: @IsraelZinc i tried to shorten the code by removing some switch cases and some other stuff

Comment: @swebdev But how exactly do you use it? What is the code you use elsewhere to consume `Results`?

Comment: @Andy i have different component for routes, this one will just print different results based on whether api endpoint '/images', '/videos' or '/news' etc

Comment: @swebdev react may not be considering your component as a functional component because sometimes you don't return HTML. Have you tried putting the default like <div>"ERROR"</div>?

Comment: `changeNum` is directly calling the `Results` component. This isn't valid in React as we never directly call a React function component, that's what the React framework is for. Remove this extraneous `Results()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const changeNum=()=>{
setNum(num+10);
console.log(num)
Results();   <--------
}
```

Calling your functional component like this is what is causing the error. This line is not needed as your component will update when you update the state.

Comment: But it doesn't, that's why

Comment: That is because when you want to update the state based on the previous value you need to use a callback inside the setNum function. It looks like setNum((prev) => prev + 10);

Comment: I am a bit confused by this line as well. This line is quite suspicious.

Comment: You also shouldn't call `console.log(num)` after a state change because changes tend to be async, and batched together. `num` won't be the state you're expecting.